# Unable to run MSTests which are data driven in nature in Build Machine

Tags: excel, tfs, datasource, tfsbuild, mstest

I have a test which is running locally fine ( in Visual Studio ) 
This is a MSTest test and it is purely data driven . The is running perfectly in my local machine using Visual Studio.

The test looks  like this

```
[TestMethod]
[TestCategory("APITests")]
[DataSource("System.Data.Odbc",
"Dsn=Excel Files;" +
"Driver={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls)};" +
"dbq=|DataDirectory|\\APITestData.xls;" +        
"defaultdir=.;" +
"driverid=790;" +
"maxbuffersize=2048;" +
"pagetimeout=5;" +
"readonly=true",
"APITestData$", 
DataAccessMethod.Sequential)]
[DeploymentItem("APITestData.xls")]
public void MyMethod(var info)
{
    //UNIT TEST CASE CODE
}
```

All is working fine and I am able to see individual results in Test Explorer of Visual Studio.

When I run this as a build in build machine, initially I got an issue like Data Source not found.

**ERROR [IM002] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Data Source not found and no default driver specified**

Later discovered that the build machine login is different and the process which runs the visual studio build is different. Hence I need to make sure on top of  user dsn , I need to set the excel odbc driver for system dsn.

After setting this up, now I am getting a different error

**The unit test adapter failed to connect to the data source or to read the data. Error details: ERROR [IM006] [Microsoft][ODBC Driver Manager] Driver's SQLSetConnectAttr failed.**

Not sure how to resolve this issue. Tried all things. But when I launch visual studio in build machine and run the test, it is working fine. 
Something to do with the service account which is running the TFS build. But not sure where to go and change the setting.

Any pointers would be very helpful.

Thanks for your time on this.

Comment: Hi Timothy, have you tried logging to the build server with the same account as the build agent account and trying to run (from you question it seems like you logged in as yourself to try).  Sometimes it's a permission issue, sometimes you might be missing some configuration in that profile.

Comment: @Etienne - Thanks for your comments. I tried everything. None worked. It seems the account which runs the build has some permissions which I am not able to realize. What I did was converted Excel provider to XML provider. Thats the only tangible solution I can achieve and keep the tests running.

Comment: ok glad you found a solution